# Javascript random text on refresh and button

Tags: javascript

I've got a (I hope) simple request. I've got a script that choose a random text under a title each time you refresh the page. Is it possible to edit that script so that the title is a button (With transparent background) and you can press it to change the text under it (But you're still able to change it by refreshing the page)?
For reference, here's the code.

```
    Title<br> 
    <script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
    var random=new Array(); 

    random[0]='Text1'; 
    random[1]='Text2'; 
    random[2]='Text3'; 
var id=Math.round(Math.random()*(random.length-1)); document.write(random[id]); </script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: so you want a button for call script and a textfield for get new text, and you want random text with new text and old text together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code into a function that writes via direct interaction with an element (not document.write), and bind the function to a button.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="newTitle()">Make new title</button>
<br />
<span id="target"></span>
```

JS:

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var titles = [
    'Title 1',
    'Title 2',
    'Title 3',
    'Title 4',
    'Title 5'
];

function newTitle () {
    var i = (Math.random() * titles.length) | 0;
    target.innerText = titles[i];
}

newTitle();
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zydryj9j/)

Comment: This one is pretty good, I used CSS to change the button and it all worked. If I want to change the random text color, where should I put the code for it?

Comment: @DatSeby: use `#target { color: whatever; }`

Comment: Nice! Thank you!
There's still a problem, though. If I want to use commas in my random text, it will output a blank line. How can I fix this?

Comment: @DatSeby: I don't understand the issue. A string with a comma will behave like any other string. Don't see any issues with: http://jsfiddle.net/zydryj9j/1/

Comment: Well, I don't know why but it wasn't working. Now it is! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var randomText = [];
randomText[0] = 'Text1';
randomText[1] = 'Text2';
randomText[2] = 'Text3';

var shuffleTitle = function() {
  var id = Math.round(Math.random() * (randomText.length - 1));
  document.getElementById('randTitle').innerHTML = randomText[id];
}
```

```css
#randTitle {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="shuffleTitle()">
  <button id="randTitle" onclick="shuffleTitle()">Title</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This one is a good answer and you can add the JavaScript function `shuffleTitle();` at the bottom of the page to handle the refresh part.

Comment: This is not what I actually wanted, but it's close to! I want something like Title Text and pressing Title, I change text. With this, pressing Title will result on Title changing in Text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `document.write(random[id])` you need to add an input element of type button with a specific id.
Then you create a click handler for that button that changes the button's text.

```
Title<br> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var random=new Array(); 

random[0]='Text1'; 
random[1]='Text2'; 
random[2]='Text3'; 
var id=Math.round(Math.random()*(random.length-1)); 

var button = document.createElement("INPUT");
button.setAttribute("type", "button");
button.setAttribute("value", random[id]);
button.setAttribute("id", "MyButton");
document.body.appendChild(button);

button.onclick = function() { // Note this is a function
    id=Math.round(Math.random()*(random.length-1)); 
    button.setAttribute("value", random[id]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<button id = "button" onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</button>

<script>
function changeText(ele) {
   var random=new Array(); 

   random[0]='Text1'; 
   random[1]='Text2'; 
   random[2]='Text3'; 
   var id=Math.round(Math.random()*(random.length-1));
   ele.innerHTML = random[id];
}(document.getElementById("button"));
</script>
```