# Javascript Random link with the text title

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, hyperlink

This code working fine on click random text appears. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31373432/1237361
But I want to display website links with the text title instead of just text. How can this be done?

Comment: Post the code in this question instead of linking to another post.

Answer (score -1):

Save an html element an in the array, specifically an `<a href="">...</a>` element, with desired values. When you have the string, you can use jQuery.parseHTML(your_string) method to output the string as html. Reference: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Ex.:

```
var titles = [
  "<a href=\"...\">Title 1</a>",
  "<a href=\"...\">Title 2</a>"
];

let html = $.parseHTML(titles[0]);
$("#log").append(html);
```

Html:

```
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I am new. can you give an example with javascript?

Comment: i added this <a href=\"http://www.testsite.com\">Title 1</a> but the link is plain text not clickable link

Comment: what is pre? I just added link URL. "<a href=\"www.testsite.com\">Title 1</a>", and its not working

Comment: When you have the string, you can use jQuery.parseHTML(your_string) method to output the string as html.